# Error importing variables from YAML file into SASS variables with Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, yaml, webpack-encore

Within the root folder of our project we are having a styleguide.yml file (containing e.g. color definitions). It should be loaded within a Symfony Twig extension as well as within SASS and JavaScript (there should be one central place to define e.g. the colors).

I have tried added the node-sass-yaml-importer package to package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass-yaml-importer": "^4.0.1",
  },
```

Within webpack.config.js I do:

```
// enables Sass/SCSS support
.enableSassLoader()

// enable autoprefixer and stuff
.enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
     options.config = {
             // the directory where the postcss.config.js file is stored
             path: './'
     };
})

.addLoader({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Apply the YAML importer via sass-loader's options.
            options: {
                importer: 'node-sass-yaml-importer'
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

When doing `yarn encore dev` I get the following error:

```
 error  in ./assets/sass/main.scss

SassError: Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'var api = require("'
        on line 1 of assets/sass/main.scss
>> var api = require("!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStyle
   ^
```

Is it because I am using the addLoader method incorrectly? How can I import variables from a .yml file with Webpack Encore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting a little bit I have found the solution. In webpack.config.js do:

```
var yamlImporter = require('node-sass-yaml-importer');

Encore
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader((options) => {
        options.sassOptions = {
            importer: yamlImporter
        };
    }, {})

    // ...
```

In main.scss do:

```
@import "../../styleguide.yml"
```

Works